# PHP traits - change value of static property in inherited class

Tags: php, inheritance, properties, traits, redefinition

So, this is my trait:

```
trait Cacheable
{
    protected static $isCacheEnabled = false;
    protected static $cacheExpirationTime = null;

    public static function isCacheEnabled()
    {
        return static::$isCacheEnabled && Cache::isEnabled();
    }

    public static function getCacheExpirationTime()
    {
        return static::$cacheExpirationTime;
    }
}
```

This is the base class:

```
abstract class BaseClass extends SomeOtherBaseClass
{
    use Cacheable;
    ...
}
```

These are my 2 final classes:

```
class Class1 extends BaseClass
{
    ...
}

class Class2 extends BaseClass
{
    protected static $isCacheEnabled = true;
    protected static $cacheExpirationTime = 3600;
    ...
}
```

Here is the part of the code which executes these classes:

```
function baseClassRunner($baseClassName)
{
    ...
    $output = null;
    if ($baseClassName::isCacheEnabled()) {
        $output = Cache::getInstance()->get('the_key');
    }
    if ($output === null) {
        $baseClass = new $baseClassName();
        $output = $baseClass->getOutput();
        if ($baseClassName::isCacheEnabled()) {
            Cache::getInstance()->set('the_key', $output);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This code doesn't work because PHP complains about defining same properties in Class2 as in Cacheable. I can't set them in their constructors because I want to read them even before running the constructor. I'm open for ideas, any help would be appreciated. :)

EDIT:

Well, I use this Cacheable trait on several places so i kind of got mixed up. :) This works fine like this. But I have another class which directly uses the Cacheable trait and when I try to do this on that class, I get the metioned error. So... Just assume that the BaseClass isn't abstract and I'm trying to set these cache properties on it. The question remains the same.

Answer (score 7):

You can not reassign trait properties.

From PHP manual http://php.net/traits

See Example #12 Conflict Resolution

> If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property
>   with the same name, otherwise an error is issued. It is an E_STRICT if
>   the class definition is compatible (same visibility and initial value)
>   or fatal error otherwise.

One solution would be to define override properties in the class

```
class Class2 extends BaseClass
{
    protected static $_isCacheEnabled = true;
    protected static $_cacheExpirationTime = 3600;
    ...
}
```

and then modify your trait as such...

```
trait Cacheable
{
    protected static $isCacheEnabled = false;
    protected static $cacheExpirationTime = null;

    public static function isCacheEnabled()
    {

        if ( Cache::isEnabled() ) {
            return isset( static::$_isCacheEnabled ) ? static::$_isCacheEnabled :
                static::$isCacheEnabled;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static function getCacheExpirationTime()
    {
        return isset ( static::$_cacheExpirationTime ) ? static::$_cacheExpirationTime :        
            static::$cacheExpirationTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this is ugly, I have 2 properties for the same thing. :/

Comment: Not 2 properties if you just have a default value in the statement `isset( static::$_isCacheEnabled ) ? static::$_isCacheEnabled : false;`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override properties, but you can override functions. So one of the possible solutions, if you're going to use the properties as given, not changing them, could be:

```
trait Cacheable {
    protected static function isCacheEnabledForClass() { return false; }

    public static function isCacheEnabled()
    {
        return static::isCacheEnabledForClass() && Cache::isEnabled();
    }
}


class Class2 extends BaseClass {
    protected static function isCacheEnabledForClass() { return true; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use defined():

```
// only defined in classes
// static $isCacheEnabled = false;

public static function isCacheEnabled()
{
    return defined(static::$isCacheEnabled ) ? static::$isCacheEnabled : false;
}
```

Or maybe you could live with the variable being protected instead of static?