# Overriding Doctrine Trait Properties

Tags: php, traits

I know you can override a `trait` **method** by declaring it in your class, I was curious if was possible to over ride a `trait` **Property** the same way. Is this safe to do? Its not in the Documentation so I am hesitant to implement this.

From the Documentation

`An inherited member from a base class is overridden by a member inserted by a Trait. The precedence order is that members from the current class override Trait methods, which in turn override inherited methods.`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: A member can be a property or a method, so I would assume so yes. Doctrine uses the DocBlock when looking at entity properties so I would assume that is overriden. The best thing to do would be to just try. Create an entity using traits, use Doctrine's schema tool to see what the SQL would be, then override with a different DocBlock and see what happens (don't forget to clear cache if you're using one).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You cannot override a trait's property in the class where the trait is used. However, you can override a trait's property in a class that extends the class where the trait is used. For example:

```
trait ExampleTrait
{
    protected $someProperty = 'foo';
}

abstract class ParentClass
{
    use ExampleTrait;
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    protected $someProperty = 'bar';
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the logic behind this ? *A son won't suffer punishment for the father's iniquity..*

Comment: Not a problem but an annoyance: In PHP5.6 it triggers a STRICT [E_STRICT][2048] Notice. The notice will explain that the Class and the Trait are defining the same property. It will also say the following: "This might be incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits instead. Class was composed.", which is funny because it is exactly the contrary of what PHP now tells us to do handle it. :)

Comment: Sometimes I think that the creators of PHP are trolling me.

Comment: The reason, if anyone still wonders, is that traits are simply copy-paste. You can't define the same property twice in a class, but you can override it in children classes - whenever you wonder about trait strangeness, think about how the code would work if you'd simply replace the `use Trait` with the code verbatim, and it all makes sense again. It's really nothing else.

Comment: @MoritzFriedrich That's what should make sense, but it doesn't. "_traits are simply copy-paste_" - correct, but they allow pasting _methods_ over the class's concrete methods _and_ provide a mechanism to resolve conflicts when needed. Why shouldn't properties have the same privilege? i tend to lean toward the troll theory from the earlier comment.

Answer (score 40):

My solution was to use the constructor, example:

```
trait ExampleTrait
{
    protected $someProperty = 'foo';
}

class MyClass
{
    use ExampleTrait;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->someProperty = 'OtherValue';
    }
}
```

Comment: @siannone Do not use static properties, it is a bad design pattern.

Comment: Using the constructor was a very valid solution and this worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't help with static properties. In one instance, I had to define a custom method `__include()` to change the static trait properties, and call it inside the `autoloader` when the class was accessed.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution, in this case using the property `updatable`.

I use this when the property is only required within the trait's methods...

```
trait MyTrait
{
    public function getUpdatableProperty()
    {
        return isset($this->my_trait_updatable) ?
            $this->my_trait_updatable:
            'default';
    }
}
```

...and using the trait in a class.

```
class MyClass
{
    use MyTrait;

    /**
     * If you need to override the default value, define it here...
     */
    protected $my_trait_updatable = 'overridden';
}
```

Answer (score -8):

You can declare a `trait` property in a class but you must keep the same definition from the `trait`. It couldn't be overridden with different definition. So, as you already has access to `trait` properties from class, it's not needed to redefined again. Think that a `trait` works as a copy paste code.

```
<?php
trait FooTrait 
{
    protected $same       = '123';
    protected $mismatch  = 'trait';
}

class FooClass 
{
    protected $same      = '123';

    // This override property produces: 
    // PHP Fatal error:  FooClass and FooTrait define the same property
    // ($mismatchValue) in the composition of FooClass. However, the definition
    // differs and is considered incompatible
    protected $mismatch  = 'class';

    use FooTrait;
}
```

Comment: Terrible answer, first the contradiction "you can override, but you can't" Make up your mind. Secondly the example does not explain anything we didn't know already, nor does it give a practical solution. Better answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20437742/208946

Comment: @goyote thanks for the link. I've replaced the word "override" by  "declare" and explicitly say that couldn't be overridden with different definition. I hope this help you.

Comment: @martinezdelariva, sorry, it is not helping.

Comment: This answer totally correct. The problem is not with the answer. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php: "f a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and initial value), otherwise a fatal error is issued."