# Why do I get "definition differs" if they are the same?

Tags: php, laravel, properties, traits

In Laravel, I have a class User that extends Authenticatable and uses a trait called Activable:

```
class User extends Authenticable {

    use Activable;

    protected $is_active_column = 'is_active';

}

trait Activable {

    /**
     * The name of the column with the activable status
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $is_active_column = 'is_active';

}
```

When I try to find a User in tinker I get this error:

```
[!] Aliasing 'User' to 'App\Models\User' for this Tinker session.

PHP Fatal error:  App\Models\User and App\Traits\Activable define the same property ($is_active_column) in the composition of App\Models\User. However, the definition differs and is considered incompatible.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior.
[The PHP documentation on **Traits** is explicit about this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.properties)

> ## Properties
>
> Traits can also define properties.
>
> ### Example #12 Defining Properties
>
> ```php
> <?php
> trait PropertiesTrait {
>     public $x = 1;
> }
>
> class PropertiesExample {
>     use PropertiesTrait;
> }
>
> $example = new PropertiesExample;
> $example->x;
> ?>
> ```
>
> **If a trait defines a property then a class can not define a property with the same name unless it is compatible (same visibility and initial value), otherwise a fatal error is issued.**
>
> ### Example #13 Conflict Resolution
>
> ```php
> <?php
> trait PropertiesTrait {
>     public $same = true;
>     public $different = false;
> }
>
> class PropertiesExample {
>     use PropertiesTrait;
>     public $same = true;
>     public $different = true; // Fatal error
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Ok, perfect, but how do I create a property in a trait that can be overriden by the class?

Comment: I suppose setters? Or trying to set them in a constructor?

Comment: OR alternatively, not using traits to override properties.

Comment: Or inherits a dummy abstruct class which using this trait: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32571920/overriding-doctrine-trait-properties/38558480#38558480